# DNS Lookup issue

Tags: domain-name-system

A friend has a website and it seems there is now (for some reason) a problem with DNS resolving. 
If I `nslookup domain.com` I get a NXDOMAIN response, but if I do `nslookup domain.com ns2.powweb.com` I get the correct lookup. (ns2.powweb.com is one of the name servers from the web hosting company)

What are some reasons this could be happening?  I'm fairly n00bish with this kind of stuff.

Comment: What is the domain in question?

Comment: it's bayonics.com

Comment: From my tests it looks like there are no name servers configured for the domain. My suggestion would be to contact the registrar or log into their control panel and designate name servers for the domain.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the domain is expired. A whois request on the domain name gives, among other info:

```
Domain Status: clientHold
```

This is clearly related to an expired domain, according to [the corresponding info page](http://www.tucowsdomains.com/whois-use-and-information/why-is-my-domain-on-%E2%80%9Cclient-hold%E2%80%9D-or-registrar-hold-in-the-whois-lookup/) from Tucows (the registrar used to register the domain).

Comment: But: `Expiration Date: 09-jan-2015`.

Comment: @EEAA Yes, they "extend" the expiration date in this circumstance.